# Syncing Prometheus and Kubewatch with Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

I want to get all events that occurred in Kubernetes cluster in some python dictionary using maybe some API to extract data from the events that occurred in the past. I found on internet that it is possible by storing all data of Kube-watch on Prometheus and later accessing it. I am unable to figure out how to set it up and see all past pod events in python. Any alternative solutions to access past events are also appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to see only Pods events or all events ?

Comment: I want to see all the Pod Events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll describe a solution that is not complicated and I think meets all your requirements.
There are tools such as [Eventrouter](https://github.com/heptiolabs/eventrouter) that take Kubernetes events and push them to a user specified sink. However, as you mentioned, you only need Pods events, so I suggest a slightly different approach.

In short, you can run the `kubectl get events --watch` command from within a Pod and collect the output from that command using a log aggregation system like [Loki](https://grafana.com/oss/loki/).

Below, I will provide a detailed step-by-step explanation.

#### 1. Running kubectl command from within a Pod

To display only Pod events, you can use:

```
$ kubectl get events --watch --field-selector involvedObject.kind=Pod
```

We want to run this command from within a Pod. For security reasons, I've created a separate `events-collector` ServiceAccount with the `view` Role assigned and our Pod will run under this ServiceAccount.
**NOTE:** I've created a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) instead of a single Pod.

```
$ cat all-in-one.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: events-collector
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: events-collector-binding
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: events-collector
    namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: view
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: events-collector
  name: events-collector
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: events-collector
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: events-collector
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: events-collector
      containers:
      - image: bitnami/kubectl
        name: test
        command: ["kubectl"]
        args: ["get","events", "--watch", "--field-selector", "involvedObject.kind=Pod"]
```

After applying the above manifest, the `event-collector` was created and collects Pod events as expected:

```
$ kubectl apply -f all-in-one.yml
serviceaccount/events-collector created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/events-collector-binding created
deployment.apps/events-collector created

$ kubectl get deploy,pod | grep events-collector
deployment.apps/events-collector           1/1     1            1           14s
pod/events-collector-d98d6c5c-xrltj            1/1     Running   0          14s

$ kubectl logs -f events-collector-d98d6c5c-xrltj
LAST SEEN   TYPE     REASON      OBJECT                                         MESSAGE
77s         Normal   Scheduled   pod/app-1-5d9ccdb595-m9d5n                     Successfully assigned default/app-1-5d9ccdb595-m9d5n to gke-cluster-2-default-pool-8505743b-brmx
76s         Normal   Pulling     pod/app-1-5d9ccdb595-m9d5n                     Pulling image "nginx"
71s         Normal   Pulled      pod/app-1-5d9ccdb595-m9d5n                     Successfully pulled image "nginx" in 4.727842954s
70s         Normal   Created     pod/app-1-5d9ccdb595-m9d5n                     Created container nginx
70s         Normal   Started     pod/app-1-5d9ccdb595-m9d5n                     Started container nginx
73s         Normal   Scheduled   pod/app-2-7747dcb588-h8j4q                     Successfully assigned default/app-2-7747dcb588-h8j4q to gke-cluster-2-default-pool-8505743b-p7qt
72s         Normal   Pulling     pod/app-2-7747dcb588-h8j4q                     Pulling image "nginx"
67s         Normal   Pulled      pod/app-2-7747dcb588-h8j4q                     Successfully pulled image "nginx" in 4.476795932s
66s         Normal   Created     pod/app-2-7747dcb588-h8j4q                     Created container nginx
66s         Normal   Started     pod/app-2-7747dcb588-h8j4q                     Started container nginx
```

#### 2. Installing Loki

You can install [Loki](https://github.com/grafana/loki) to store logs and process queries. Loki is like Prometheus, but for logs :). The easiest way to install Loki is to use the [grafana/loki-stack](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/loki-stack) Helm chart:

```
$ helm repo add grafana https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts
"grafana" has been added to your repositories

$ helm repo update
...
Update Complete. ⎈Happy Helming!⎈

$ helm upgrade --install loki grafana/loki-stack


$ kubectl get pods | grep loki
loki-0                            1/1     Running   0          76s
loki-promtail-hm8kn               1/1     Running   0          76s
loki-promtail-nkv4p               1/1     Running   0          76s
loki-promtail-qfrcr               1/1     Running   0          76s
```

#### 3. Querying Loki with LogCLI

You can use the [LogCLI](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/getting-started/logcli/) tool to run LogQL queries against a Loki server. Detailed information on installing and using this tool can be found in the [LogCLI documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/getting-started/logcli/#installation). I'll demonstrate how to install it on Linux:

```
$ wget https://github.com/grafana/loki/releases/download/v2.2.1/logcli-linux-amd64.zip

$ unzip logcli-linux-amd64.zip
Archive:  logcli-linux-amd64.zip
  inflating: logcli-linux-amd64
  
$ mv logcli-linux-amd64 logcli

$ sudo cp logcli /bin/

$ whereis logcli
logcli: /bin/logcli
```

To query the Loki server from outside the Kubernetes cluster, you may need to expose it using the [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) resource:

```
$ cat ingress.yml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: loki-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: loki
              servicePort: 3100
            path: /
            
 
$ kubectl apply -f ingress.yml
ingress.networking.k8s.io/loki-ingress created

$ kubectl get ing
NAME           CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS         PORTS   AGE
loki-ingress   <none>   *      <PUBLIC_IP>      80      19s
```

Finally, I've created a simple python script that we can use to query the Loki server:
**NOTE:** We need to set the `LOKI_ADDR` environment variable as described in the [documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/getting-started/logcli/#example). You need to replace the `<PUBLIC_IP>` with your Ingress IP.

```
$ cat query_loki.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

os.environ['LOKI_ADDR'] = "http://<PUBLIC_IP>"

os.system("logcli query '{app=\"events-collector\"}'")


$ ./query_loki.py
...
2021-07-02T10:33:01Z {} 2021-07-02T10:33:01.626763464Z stdout F 0s          Normal    Pulling       pod/backend-app-5d99cf4b-c9km4                               Pulling image "nginx"
2021-07-02T10:33:00Z {} 2021-07-02T10:33:00.836755152Z stdout F 0s          Normal    Scheduled     pod/backend-app-5d99cf4b-c9km4                               Successfully assigned default/backend-app-5d99cf4b-c9km4 to gke-cluster-1-default-pool-328bd2b1-288w
2021-07-02T10:33:00Z {} 2021-07-02T10:33:00.649954267Z stdout F 0s          Normal    Started       pod/web-app-6fcf9bb7b8-jbrr9                                 Started container nginx2021-07-02T10:33:00Z {} 2021-07-02T10:33:00.54819851Z stdout F 0s          Normal    Created       pod/web-app-6fcf9bb7b8-jbrr9                                 Created container nginx
2021-07-02T10:32:59Z {} 2021-07-02T10:32:59.414571562Z stdout F 0s          Normal    Pulled        pod/web-app-6fcf9bb7b8-jbrr9                                 Successfully pulled image "nginx" in 4.228468876s
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is very useful. But I am not able to figure out step 3. I have set up Loki and I am able to access all pod events using grafana and loki, but I can't figure out how to import this data in python program. Also, which service should I expose using Ingress? Currently, I have loki, loki-grafana, loki-stack and loki-headless running in my cluster.

Comment: @Dragnoid99 I edited my answer and provided more details. You need to expose the `loki` service if you want to access it from outside the cluster. Additionally I've created a simple python script to illustrate how it may work.