# How to kubectl get event of node (not pod)?

Tags: kubernetes

When describing a node, there are history conditions that show up.

```
Conditions:
  Type                 Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----                 ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  NetworkUnavailable   False   Tue, 10 Aug 2021 10:55:23 +0700   Tue, 10 Aug 2021 10:55:23 +0700   CalicoIsUp                   Calico is running on this node
  MemoryPressure       False   Mon, 16 Aug 2021 12:02:18 +0700   Thu, 12 Aug 2021 14:55:48 +0700   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure         False   Mon, 16 Aug 2021 12:02:18 +0700   Thu, 12 Aug 2021 14:55:48 +0700   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure          False   Mon, 16 Aug 2021 12:02:18 +0700   Thu, 12 Aug 2021 14:55:48 +0700   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready                False   Mon, 16 Aug 2021 12:02:18 +0700   Mon, 16 Aug 2021 11:54:02 +0700   KubeletNotReady              PLEG is not healthy: pleg was last seen active 11m17.462332922s ago; threshold is 3m0s
```

I have 2 questions:

1. I think those conditions only show the latest status. How can I access the full-time history of the previous conditions?
2. Suggest me the tool that converts node condition to something like pod events for log centralize.

Comment: *Note*, if someone wants to store events for longer duration then set `--event-ttl` flag in api-server args. by default its `1h0m0s`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right, the `kubectl describe <NODE_NAME>` command shows the current condition status (`False`/`True`).

You can monitor Nodes events using the following command:

```
# kubectl get events --watch --field-selector involvedObject.kind=Node 
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON                 OBJECT         MESSAGE
3m50s       Warning   EvictionThresholdMet   node/kworker   Attempting to reclaim inodes
44m         Normal    NodeHasDiskPressure    node/kworker   Node kworker status is now: NodeHasDiskPressure
```

To view only status related events, you can use `grep` with the previous command:

```
# kubectl get events --watch --field-selector involvedObject.kind=Node | grep "status is now"
44m         Normal    NodeHasDiskPressure    node/kworker   Node kworker status is now: NodeHasDiskPressure
```

By default, these events are retained for [1 hour](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/da53a247633cd91bd8e9818574279f3b04aed6a5/cmd/kube-apiserver/app/options/options.go#L71-L72). However, you can run the `kubectl get events --watch --field-selector involvedObject.kind=Node` command from within a Pod and collect the output from that command using a log aggregation system like [Loki](https://grafana.com/oss/loki/). I've described this approach with a detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68212477/14801225).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `kubectl describe node <nodename> --show-events=true`and `kubectl get events` which will show you the events related to the described object which are persisted in etcd and provide high-level information on what is happening in the cluster.

Comment: I tested `kubectl describe node xxx-yyy-app-zzzz --show-events=true` with k8s `v1.20.6` it don't show previous conditions of Node. It just shows more relate data like pod resource consumption and system info, etc...

Answer (score 0):

kubectl get events --field-selector involvedObject.kind=Node,type!=Normal --sort-by='.lastTimestamp'

Note: you can combine multiple field-selectors by using commas. I came up with this gem that's super useful for debugging clusters with 100's of nodes, as it only shows relevant data !=Normal filters the kruft and sorts it by time.